# Concatenate all files in folder and subfolder with newline to one file

Tags: bash, concatenation, cat

I have some folders and subfoldes with .txt and other extensions (like .py, .html) and I want to concatenate all to one .txt file

I try this:

```
find . -type f -exec cat {} + > test.txt
```

Input:

```
txt1.txt:
aaaaa
test.py
print("a")
htmltest1.html:
<head></head>
```

Output:

```
aaaaaprint("a")<head></head>
```

Desired outup:

```
aaaaa
print("a")
<head></head>
```

So, how to modify this bash-command to get my desired output? I want to paste newline after each printed file

Comment: If you think of the command you give to `-exec` as a script you have full control over - would that help? `find . -type f -exec myscript {} + > test.txt` - Do you see where I'm going with that?
`for file in "$@" ...`

Comment: I just tried your find command, and it worked fine, except that I specified a directory, not just `.` to avoid having test.txt itself as an input.  I also tried `find . -name *.txt -exec cat {} \; >all-cat.txt`, which provided the same result.  Can't reproduce.

Comment: Probably exclude the output file within `find`:  `find . -type f ! -name 'test.txt' -exec cat {} + > test.txt`, but I can't reproduce your output. Might be a carriage returns from your files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the last lines of your files are not terminated with the newline character, which means they don't fulfill the POSIX definition of a text file, which may yield weird results like this.

Probably all graphical text editors I've used allow you not to put a terminating newline, and a lot of people won't put it, presumably because the editor makes it look like there's a redundant empty line at the end.
This may be the reason why some people couldn't reproduce your issue - presumably they created the sample files with well-behaving tools such as `cat` or `vim` or `nano`, or they did put the newline characters at the end.

So here's the issue:

```sh
user@host:~$ find . -type f -exec cat {} \;
aaaaaprint("a")<head></head>user@host:~$
```

To avoid these sorts of problems in the future, you should always hit `<enter>` after the last line of text in your file when using a graphical text editor. However, sometimes you have to work with files produced by other users, which might not know this sort of stuff, so:
here is a quick and dirty workaround (concatenating with an additional file which only contains the newline character):

```sh
user@host:~$ echo '' > /tmp/newline.txt
user@host:~$ find . -type f -exec cat {} /tmp/newline.txt \;
aaaaa
print("a")
<head></head>
user@host:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `-E` parameter on `cat` so it prints a `$` at end of lines.
Then use `sed` to strip those out, with a literal `\$` symbol anchored with `$` at the end.

```
find . -type f -exec cat -E {} + | sed s'/\$$//' > test.txt
```